# creating a graphic interface for Python 2.5.4

Tags: python

I just downloaded and successfully installed python 2.5.4 ,
from here  [Python version 2.5.4](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4/)

tried to search for an IDLE for Python 2.5.4 but no success......
   Is there a tutorial or anything to help me install the IDLE for Python 2.5.4

Help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 12.04 you already have python 2.7 installed so, unless you need 2.5.4, there is no need to install it.

To install IDLE:

`sudo apt-get install idle`

Or you can install it from the software center searching for IDLE in the search box.

Before, you could install idle for python2.5 with:

`sudo apt-get install idle-python2.5`  but version 2.5 is not anymore included in Ubuntu 12.04 repo so if you can't work with version 2.7, you may have to download v2.5  [manually (and dependencies)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/idle-python2.5) and install it manually with `sudo dpkg -i path/to/package` if you get a deb file or compile it.

Comment: I need 2.5.4 version for educational purposes, does this IDLE also work for 2.5.4??

Comment: I don't think 2.7 version will work with 2.5 python because if I remember well there are differences in TK. Edited the answer.

Comment: I downloaded the .deb file, but when opening it the ubuntu software centre opens saying "dependency is not satisfiable : python 2.5 "....????